# AWS EC2 Looses public Internet after install Visual Studio 2013

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio, build-server

I am trying to setup a build server on an AWS EC2.   It is a base Windows 2012 R2, MsSQL 2014 and TeamCity 9.x.  At this point the public internet works just fine.  I can do windows updates and TeamCity can pull the project from Github.

The project that needs to be built is a .NET application with Unit Test written in MSTest.  To accomplish this, the build is being done through Visual Studio 2013 with the TeamCity plugin.  (this setup works fine on another cloud hosting provider).

As soon as I install Visual Studio 2013 onto the AWS EC2 instance, the public internet is no longer reachable.  Support unfortunately has not been able to provide any solutions/

--Update--

- I was able to narrow it down to Visual Studio Ultimate, when i installed it, internet stopped working, uninstalled it and the internet began again
- As a work around I installed VS 2013 community edition and AWS appears to like that.

Comment: No experience with AWS, but i use a ton of virtual machines and quite a lto have VS installed. NEVER had that issue. I think you bark the wrong tree - the real reason is something different.

Comment: That is a possibility. all new to me.  I setup a VM outside of AWS this setup works.  I also tested 3 EC2 instances,  all three lost internet as soon as I install VS2013.

Comment: @Chadit Are you ****ing joking? I'm having exactly the same issue. I dunno wtf's going on. I'm in ap-southeast-2 and basing the image off Windows Server 2012 R2. As soon as I install visual studio 2013 ultimate and reboot, boom the internet dies. I can RDP into it as well but there's no internet.